# UIButton works on simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uibutton

My UIButton works flawless in simulator but not on the iPhone with iOS4

```
picButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, 80, 90, 150)];
[picButton addTarget:self action:@selector(mailIt:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[picButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"save_2.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[picButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"save_2.png"]  forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

On the iPhone the button is displayed correctly, and it looks like it's pressed but the action isn't launched.

Later edit:
This is the code for mailIt:

```
-(IBAction) mailIt : (id)delegate{
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[picker setSubject:@"title!"];
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"messagestring", imagename];
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
}
```

Comment: pls check if the function mailIt is called and pls post the code for the function mailIt

Comment: Please put an NSLog as the first line of mailIt: to see if that method is actually being called on the device.

Comment: You could use NSLog or just place a simple breakpoint on the first line of mailIt:

Comment: Are you sure you press the button and release your finger *inside* the button? Since you're using `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` :)!

Comment: UIControlEventTouchUpInside works. The problem is I don't have any testing device for debugging, I only get the tester's feedback. The function mailIt is called correctly on the simulator.

Comment: pls provide the code of the function mailIt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

Should have been

```
picker.mailComposeDelegate = camera;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check if your device is configured to send mails since you are using MFMailComposeViewController but you did not check in your code whether the device is capable of displaying the view using the canSendMail method.

To configure the device to send mails, you need to launch the mail app and set up your email.